# How do you specify either one type or another

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

here's the general gist of what I am trying to do

```
type A = number | any[]  

declare const a: A

a.slice(1) // type error slice does not exist on Type A
```

[link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20A%20%3D%20number%20%7C%20any%5B%5D%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20a%3A%20A%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.slice(1)%0D%0A)

How do I specify the return value of a function if indeed it can be either a number or an array?

I assumed that is how the `|` worked ie.

```
type A = number | string | any[]  

declare const a: A // a can be either a number, string or array

a.slice(0,1) // a is a string or array
.concat([1,2]) // a is an array
```

Comment: Think about it like this: why should TS let you call a function that only exists on arrays on an object that could also be a number? That wouldn't be type-safe.

Comment: (And just to amend this, given your example TS is really right here: this function doesn't exist on a number, so passing a number would simply cause a runtime error; what do you expect to happen?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if a is array an in first example

```
type A = number | any[]  

const a: A = []; // add a value like this ts will infer that a is an array 
a.slice(1);
```

or you can use casting

```
(a as any[]).slice(1);
```

With TypeScript 2.0, the type checker analyses all possible flows of control in statements and expressions to produce the most specific type possible (the narrowed type) at any given location for a local variable or parameter that is declared to have a union type.

```
type A = number | string | any[]  

declare const a: A ;  // assigning a value 

if (typeof a === 'string' ){
  console.log(a.toString());
}else if (typeof a === 'number') {
  console.log(a++);
} else if ( a instanceof Array) {
 a.slice(0,1).concat([1,2])
}
```

[TypeScript 2.0: Control Flow Based Type Analysis](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/09/30/typescript-2-0-control-flow-based-type-analysis)

Comment: Type guards are also a keyword worth looking up for this.